# How to create Announcement in MS teams using incoming webhook APIs

Tags: python, api, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm able to send normal messages to ms teams by creating incoming webhook in connectors. I wanted to post announcements using incoming webhook.

This is the payload which i used for normal messages.

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"summary": "Summary text",
"themeColor": "007f00",
"sections": [
    {
        "themeColor": "007f00",
        "text": "<p>Pragaraph Text</p>"
    }
]}
```

Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Announcements using Webhooks/ Any APIs is not supported.

Comment: Do you have any source about this?